Form submitted file MailApp
I cant figure out how to get a file that is submitted in a form to send as a email.
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var responses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var fileItem = responses[1]; // Assuming the file is the first response
  var responses = e.response.getItemResponses().map(item => item.getResponse());
  // Get the file response
  var uFile = fileItem.getResponse();

  // Email subject and body
  var subject = "New File Uploaded";
  var body = "A new file has been uploaded.\n\n";

  if (uFile) {
    // If a file is uploaded, include the file details in the email

    
    body += responses
  MailApp.sendEmail("someRandomEmail@gmail.com", subject, body,
    { attachments: uFile });
    Logger.log("File sent successfully!");
  } 
}

I have looked over a few forms to find anything but nope. So I come hoping some one can help.

The attachments property of the options object of MailApp.sendEmail should be an array of Interface BlobSource objects.
The example below works for a Google Form with File Upload as the first question.
function formSubmitHandler(e) {
    const formResponse = e.response;
    // Response to the first question
    const itemResponse = formResponse.getItemResponses()[0];
    if(itemResponse.getItem().getType() === FormApp.ItemType.FILE_UPLOAD){        
        const file = DriveApp.getFileById(itemResponse.getResponse());
        const recipient = "Please provide an email address here";
        const subject = "Demo sending file uploded as attachmet";
        const body = "Please checkout the attachment";
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {attachments: [file]});
        Logger.log("Email sent");
    } else {
        Logger.log("Email was not sent");
    }
}

Please note that the above code should be added to the Apps Script project bound to a Form, and an installable trigger should be created.
References

MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events


Sending Email on Form Submit Using GmailApp
A modified version of the script which would be for the form it can handle multiple questions and that answers would attach in your code: body += responses.
I opted to use GmailApp for the reason for the future if OP wants to use it for managing emails, especially if you plan to work with features like threads, labels, and more.
Code.gs
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var response = e.response;
  var itemResponses = response.getItemResponses();
  var responses = itemResponses.map(item => item.getResponse().concat("\n"));
  responses.shift()
  var file = itemResponses[0].getResponse();  // returns the file id

  var subject = "New File Uploaded";
  var body = "A new file has been uploaded.\n\n";

  if (file) {
    body += responses.toString().replace(",","");
    GmailApp.sendEmail("someRandomEmail@gmail.com", subject, body, { attachments: [DriveApp.getFileById(file)] });
    Logger.log("File sent successfully!");
  }
}

Sample Output:

Sample Form:

References:
Installable Triggers

The question's code indicates that the original poster (OP) uses a form submit trigger for a Google Form. However, the answer does not explain this; instead, it suggests using a spreadsheet trigger. Additionally, it fails to address why the OP's code isn't functioning correctly. It's important to remember that Stack Overflow is focused on solving specific programming issues rather than sharing entire scripts. For sharing scripts, platforms like blogs or GitHub are more appropriate.

@Wicket Thank you for the feedback, I thought OP is using Spreadsheet for the line  var fileItem = responses[1]; since on the spreadsheet it would be the second element. I modified my script that works on the google forms similar to what OP's doing.

Don't add a "Edit" Section,. Posts already have a edit history an edit descrption field.

It's now modified thanks again!
